# Convert tuple to string in python 3

Tags: python, mysql, string, tuples

I'm tyring to receive data from mysql database via python .  In the database I have the value ON_1 when I receive it in python I receive it as tuple :  (('ON_1',),) Any help to get it in python in its normal form ON_1

Answer (score 1):

Access the first value of the first tuple, and then access the first value of the resulting tuple:

```
result[0][0]
```

This gets the first item of the first tuple to get `("ON_1",)` and then gets the first item of *that* tuple to result in `"ON_1"`.

Answer (score 0):

A nested tuple can be access just like a nested list.

```
>>> x =  (('ON_1',),)
>>>
>>> x[0] # this accesses the first level
('ON_1',)
>>> x[0][0] # this accesses the second level
'ON_1'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please edit your answer to add some explanation.